# Laravel form binding with one to one relationships

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have an Account model that has a polymorphic relation to an Address model. This is set up as a one-to-one releationship set up like so:

Account:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne('Address', 'hasAddress', 'add_hasaddress_type', 'add_hasaddress_id', 'act_id');
}
```

Address:

```
public function hasAddress()
{
    return $this->morphTo('hasAddress', 'add_hasaddress_type', 'add_hasaddress_id');
}
```

On my form to edit the account, I also have the address fields. I can bind my account object simply enough by doing:

```
{{ Form::model($account, array('route' => array('accounts/edit', $account->act_id), 'method' => 'put')) }}
    {{ Form::label('act_name', 'Account Name:') }}
    {{ Form::text('act_name', Input::old('act_name')) }}
```

and that fills in the fields properly. But, how do I populate the address fields? From what I researched, I need to do:

```
{{ Form::text('address.add_city', Input::old('address.add_city')) }}
```

To access the relation's values, but this doesn't work.

I also tried

```
{{ Form::text('address[add_city]', Input::old('address[add_city]')) }}
```

as suggested by a SO with a similar title. Both of these I tried with and without the old input. Does this just not work with poymorphic relations or am I doing something wrong?

Also, how do you handle these forms in the controller?

Nothing about relations is in the form model binding documentation, and doing a search mainly brings up people asking for one-to-many binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works with any *-to-one relation (for many-to-many, ie. a collection of models it won't work):

```
// prepare model with related data - eager loading
$account = Account::with('address')->find($someId);

// or lazy loading
$account = Account::find($someId);
$account->load('address');

// view template
{{ Form::model($account, ...) }}
  Account: {{ Form::text('acc_name') }}
  City: {{ Form::text('address[add_city]') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

No need for `Input::old` or whatsoever, `null` is enough as default value. Laravel will fill the data in this order ([Docs are wrong here!](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding)):

```
1. old input
2. bound data
3. value passed to the helper
```

Mind that you **must** load the relation (dynamic call won't work in this case).

Another thing is processing the input later - Laravel will not automatically hydrate the related model, so you need something like:

```
$accountData = Input::only(['acc_name', ... other account fields]);
// or
$accountData = Input::except(['address']);
// validate etc, then:
$account->fill($accountData);

$addressData = Input::get('address');
// validate ofc, then:
$account->address->fill($addressData);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. It looks like I was just missing the part where you load the related data. I didn't realize that's something you had to do.